# c++ class method thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, oop, methods

i have a class that has a method that needs to be running continuously but also be able to receive input from user. So i thought i would make the method run separately using a thread.

the code looks something like this(just the backbone):

```
class SystemManager
{
private:
    int command;
    bool commandAcK;

    bool running;

    //other vars

public:

    SystemManager()
    {
        //initialisation
    }

    void runningAlgorithm()
    {

        while (running)
        {
            if (commandAcK)
            {
                //solve command
            }

            //run algorithm
            //print results
        }

    }


    void readCmd()
    {

        cin >> command;
        commandAcK = true;

    }



};




int main()
{

    SystemManager *SM = new SystemManager;

    thread tRunning = SM->runningAlgorithm();


}
```

now the errors look like this:

*no suitable constructor exists to convert from "`void`" to "`std::thread`"*

> ***Error  C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'void' to 'std::thread'***

i have found a new method and it doesn't give me any errors

```
std::thread tRunning(&SystemManager::runningAlgorithm, SystemManager());
```

the first thing i don't understand is that this method doesn't use an instance of the class just the generic function. How can i link it to a specific instance? I need it so it can read the values of the variables.

Secondly what does `"&"` in front of SystemManager do?

```
(&SystemManager::runningAlgorithm)
```

Thirdly is there a better way of doing it? Do you have any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor for `std::thread` accepts a *functor*, and optionally it's arguments. A functor is anything that can be "called" using `operator()`.

Then it starts a thread and inside that thread calls your functor.

```
std::thread tRunning(&SystemManager::runningAlgorithm, SystemManager());
```

This will call the member function `SystemManager::runningAlgorithm`, passing in the only argument being `this` (`SystemManager()` creates a temporary instance).
Remember that member functions always accept `this` as the first argument.

`&SystemManager::runningAlgorithm` returns the address of the member function `runningAlgorithm` from the class `SystemManager`.

In modern C++ this code can be simplified (i.e. made more readable) with a lambda:

```
std::thread tRunning([]{ SystemManager().runningAlgorithm(); });
```

Answer (score 2):

`std::thread tRunning(&SystemManager::runningAlgorithm, SystemManager());` does use an instance of your class.  The instance it uses is `SystemManager()` which is a temporary and only available to the thread.  If you need to share the instance then you need to create one yourself and pass it by reference to the thread like

```
SystemManager sys_manager;
std::thread tRunning([&](){sys_manager.runningAlgorithm();});
```

And now your call site and your thread have the same instance.

Also note that `command` and `commandAck` need to be protected by some sort of synchronization since you can write to them while reading causing a [data race](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Threads_and_data_races) and subsequently [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  Using [`std::atmoic`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) should work for you.

Comment: +1 for the synchronization, but why a lambda? Why building a closure when you already have everything you need there?

Comment: @marco6 I used the lambda as for me it is an easy way to bind a reference to the function.  I can't quite remember how to do it using bind or the thread constructor but I know this works so it is what I do.  I also think it is more expressive of exactly what I want to happen.

Comment: sure! Just one thing: to remember, if sys_manager goes out of scope with the other thread still running, it will be a real mess...

Comment: @marco6 Of course there is still that.  I would use a `std::shared_ptr` if the guarantee needs to be put in place.  Really though it is only needed if `std::thread` is passed out of the scope.  if it is not then the thread will end before `sys_manger` is destroyed and you have no problem(thanks scope and order of construction/destruction rules).

Comment: I wouldn't let a beginner write lambda's like that (`[&]` or `[=]` can be dangerous).

Comment: @RustyX What is dangerous about `[=]`?

Comment: @NathanOliver poor performance of course (can accidentally deep-copy a huge map, for example).

Comment: @RustyX OK.  I thought you were talking about this example, not the general case.  IMHO in this case I see nothing wrong with using a reference unless the thread is going to leave the scope.

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
thread tRunning = SM->runningAlgorithm();
```

takes *the result* of running `SM->runningAlgorithm()` (a `void`), and tries to construct a thread from it. If you look at [the relevant constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread), though, you can see it needs a function-like argument (with possibly arguments).

One way of running it is through a lambda function:

```
thread tRunning(
    [SM](){SM->runningAlgorithm();});
```

---

Two other things to note:

1. You should join the thread before its destructor is called, in this case:

   ```
   tRunning.join();
   ```
2. You have a (short lived) memory leak. Why not just create it on the stack?

   ```
   SystemManager SM;

   thread tRunning(
       [&](){SM.runningAlgorithm();});

   tRunning.join();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Uhm... I guesss you need to study some of the basic concepts of c++, before going multithread.

However... In your code,

```
    thread tRunning = SM->runningAlgorithm();
```

tries to put the *result* of your function (that is void... ) inside a variable of type thread... Non likely to be right.

Instead, your second code takes 2 arguments:

```
std::thread tRunning(
        &SystemManager::runningAlgorithm, //a pointer to a method (a pointer to the code of your function, and that is why you use the "&", even though you could have left that out)
        SystemManager()); // An instance of the value, built on the stack.
```

I guest that you are confused by the lack of the word "new" (coming from higher level language?), but that's how it works here:

```
SystemManager sm = SystemManager(); // <- variable created on the stack, will be automatically destroyed when out of scope
SystemManager *psm = new SystemManager(); // Created in the heap, while in the stack remains just a pointer to it. 
//You will need to delete it when done with :
delete psm;
```

To answer the question

> How can i link it to a specific instance? I need it so it can read the values of the variables.

You can do:

```
int main()
{

    SystemManager SM; // = SystemManager(); // <- this is not needed

    std::thread tRunning(SystemManager::runningAlgorithm, SM);
    // Access SM as you need

    // REMEMBER TO CLOSE & JOIN THE THREAD!
    tRunning.join();
}
```

I still think you should first get used to the underlying concepts or it will be really difficult to go on.